# How to track down process in auth log

Tags: linux, security

I have a server running ubuntu 14.04.   In /var/log/auth.log there is some kind of automated process which runs every hour and I want to find out what the process is.

I've already determined there are no cron jobs scheduled by any users.  All I have to go by is the following sample lines in auth.log every hour:

```
Dec  2 03:17:01 fi CRON[23537]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec  2 03:17:01 fi CRON[23537]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec  2 04:17:01 fi CRON[23557]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Any ideas on how to track this down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've already determined there are no cron jobs scheduled by any users.

You probably missed the system-wide cron jobs in `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d/*`.

If there appear to be none, you can attach `strace` to the cron process to see what files it reads, or what commands it executes:

```
strace -p 23537 -e file
strace -p 23537 -f -e execve [-s 10000]
```

In older systems, cron might have been compiled without automatic reload support, so if someone manually removed the jobs from /etc/crontab but didn't reload cron, they would continue to be run until someone did trigger a reload.

Comment: Indeed there was a cron job in /etc/crontab called run-parts that runs every hour looking for hourly scripts to kick off.  Never knew about that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`atop`](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/analyzing-linux-server-performance-atop)**.

When installed it will start to automatically account processes and their resource usage and write the data to log files. You can wait a bit to gather enough data and then inspect the logs or parse them.

For example, after gathering logs, to check what process was running, I would recommend the following command:

```
atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_<current date> -b 03:16 -e 03:18 -P PRG | grep -P 'PRG.*\s23557\s\('
```

This will:

1. Read the log file from the current day between 03:16 and 03:18
2. Output the data in a machine-parseable output with generic data about the processes (this will include process name)
3. Search for the line where process with PID 23557 was accounted so you can see what the process name is, enclosed in brackets. The grep pattern is for higher accuracy - the line always starts with `PRG`, value columns are space-separated (PID is a separate column), and the column after PID is the process name enclosed in brackets (starts with `(`).